# ORA-27369: job of type EXECUTABLE failed with exit code: There are no child processes to wait for

Tags: oracle-11g, jobs

I have existing .bat file where i call FDSLoader64.exe on daily basis to update following tables.

FF_ADVANCED_AF
FF_ADVANCED_SAF
FF_BASIC_SAF
FF_BASIC_AF

FDSLoader64.exe is supposed to download latest txt files related to resepctive tables from FTP and upload it.

After update is successfull FDSLoader64.exe updates metadata tables where we can know whether update was successfull or not.

To do this i have **created a PROGRAM** in Oracle 11g as follows

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.DISABLE(name=>'FDS_DEMO.FF_V3', force=>TRUE);
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE(name=>'FDS_DEMO.FF_V3');  
END;
```

**Created a schedule** for it as daily it should run at 11:30 AM.

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_attribute( name => '"FDS_DEMO"."DAILY_9AM"', attribute => 'repeat_interval', value => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI;BYHOUR=11;BYMINUTE=30;BYSECOND=0');
END;
```

At last i have **created a job** which runs the program using the schedule.

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_attribute( name => '"FDS_DEMO"."FF_V3_GENESIS"', attribute => 'job_priority', value => 1);
END; 
/
```

Schedule had successfully ran at 11:30 on 24th June 2019. As per metadata tables we can confirm that data was uploaded to the tables successfully but when i see content of user_scheduler_job_run_details it shows me results as follows.

[image]

```
**Complete error code is as follows.**
"ORA-27369: job of type EXECUTABLE failed with exit code: There are no 
child processes to wait for.
STANDARD_ERROR="2019/06/24 11:30:16  INFO>: config.xml is at the latest        
version 2.10, continuing.
2019/06/24 11:30:21  INFO>: FDSLoader version 2.13.1.0
2019/06/24 11:30:21  INFO>: Emptying directory D:\FDSLoader\d""
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156188/running-bat-file-with-scheduled-task-and-failing-with-there-are-no-child-proces

Comment: Thanks a lot Balazs Papp. That solved my issue. Sorry for the repeat question.